# Vertical alignment for desktop icons in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, desktop, icons, alignment

Is there a way to enable vertical alignment of icons (so that icons span to horizontal lines) on desktop in Ubuntu? Similar behavior can be found in Windows desktop. Please note, that horizontal alignment works as in should. Here is an example of the problems that I experience:

[image]

I would like to have these icons to be in a single row, so it's easier to organize items on the desktop without the need to move them pixel-wise manually.

Comment: i don't think this is a feature so they can justify under file names instead of icons on auto-arrange...just a thought

Comment: just confirmed the behavior for auto arrange with long file names, the desktop manager adjusts alignment by up to 3 lines of file name you can still read the name.  if you find a way to do it, it will probably be an app or hackish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears there no way to do that. At least not in 12.04 and 10.04.

Comment: Meanwhile, on 14.04 and 15.04: no joy either.

Answer (score 1):

Right click on your desktop, and click "**keep aligned**". This automatically snaps the icons to grid.

[image: Image of "keep aligned"]

Comment: This only keeps them aligned horizontally.

Comment: @SergiyByelozyorov No, it also keeps them aligned horizontally. (at least it does in Ubuntu 13.04)

Comment: This doesn't work in Ubuntu 12.04. In fact, I'm not sure what "Keep Aligned" is supposed to do.

Comment: It keeps them in vertical lines, but horizontal is absolutely hideous.